# Way to protect documents to never be shown in query results

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to have a middleware that based on a condition protects or hides a document from any kind of indexing or querying. for example consider this pseudo code:

```
Schema.pre('any query',function(next){
    if(document.status !== 'published') document.allowQuering = false;
}
```

or:

```
Schema.pre('save',function(next){
    if(this.status !== 'published') this.allowQuering = false;
}
```

and this should make sure that those documents without status of published will not show in queries or populate from other documents etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is such a way.

You can have another collection where you can store the documents which should not be displayed. Later when condition satisfied, you can move that document to the original collection.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using mongoose use select property but beware it will not work with
aggregation for aggregation you should always create a helper method

password: { type: String, select: false }